# Drawing geometries with Direct2D in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

How can I create geometry object which will be compatible with pRenderTarget in MFC application? That is, I have:

```
LRESULT CWorkSpaceBar::OnDrawDirect2D(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    CHwndRenderTarget* pRenderTarget = (CHwndRenderTarget*)lParam;

    pRenderTarget->FillGeometry(//<<-- here I need a geometry, i.e. an Ellipse Geometry

}
```

I've tried:

```
ID2D1EllipseGeometry *m_pEllipseGeometry = nullptr;
    ID2D1Factory *pFactory = nullptr;
    m_pEllipseGeometry->GetFactory(&pFactory);
    pFactory->CreateEllipseGeometry(ellipse, &m_pEllipseGeometry);
    pRenderTarget->FillGeometry(m_pEllipseGeometry, m_pBlackBrush);
```

Alas, I'm getting an error saying:

> Error    C2664    'void CRenderTarget::FillGeometry(CD2DGeometry
>   *,CD2DBrush *,CD2DBrush *)':
>
> cannot convert argument 1 from 'ID2D1EllipseGeometry *' to
>   'CD2DGeometry *'

I understand that there is a conflict with types, but from what I've managed to check there isn't a MFC class that inherits from CD2DGeometry, CD2DGeometry is an abstract class and pRenderTarget expects CD2DGeometry* as its first argument.
I'm really confused.
Any help really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID2D1EllipseGeometry *m_pEllipseGeometry = nullptr;
ID2D1Factory *pFactory = nullptr;
m_pEllipseGeometry->GetFactory(&pFactory);
```

This will fail because `m_pEllipseGeometry` is `nullptr`. To use MFC, try this example:

```
pRenderTarget->Clear({ 1, 1, 1, 1 });
CRect rc(0, 0, 100, 100);
CD2DRectF d2d_rect(rc);
CD2DEllipse ellipse(&d2d_rect);
CD2DSolidColorBrush brush(pRenderTarget, { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1 });
pRenderTarget->FillEllipse(ellipse, &brush);
```

Looking at header files, it seems MFC doesn't support `ID2D1EllipseGeometry` at all. To get access to `pFactory`, use this example:

```
if (SUCCEEDED(D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &pFactory))
{
    ...
    pFactory->Release();
}
```

There is also `AfxGetD2DState()->GetDirect2dFactory()`. You can use `CreateHwndRenderTarget` to get `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`

Comment: Semirani Hi, thank you for your answer, unfortunately there was little misunderstanding. I do not want to fill ellipse, I want to fill ID2D1EllipseGeometry which is different animal to an CD2DEllipse. If you know how to solve it, that would be really great.

Comment: MFC doesn't have a class for `ID2D1EllipseGeometry` You can work with `pFactory` and `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` to get access to main APIs